# Upper limit on the number of Azure logic apps that can be created in a resource group/subscription?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

1. Any limit on number of logic apps that can be created in a resource group/subscription.
2. Any limit on number of logic apps that can be created per minute.

We essentially want to create logic apps(many per minute) to create scheduled triggers to drop messages on service bus and delete these logic apps when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Workflows per region per subscription 1000 (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config))
2. This would be related to the Azure Resource Manager.

> For each subscription and tenant, Resource Manager limits read requests to 15,000 per hour and write requests to 1,200 per hour.
>   These limits apply to each Azure Resource Manager instance; there are
>   multiple instances in every Azure region, and Azure Resource Manager
>   is deployed to all Azure regions. So, in practice, limits are
>   effectively much higher than those listed above, as user requests are
>   generally serviced by many different instances.+
>
> If your application or script reaches these limits, you need to
>   throttle your requests.

from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits).

HTH

Comment: For 1. it is specified that "These limits apply to a single logic app definition.". So is it safe to say that we would be only limited by the ARM limit per geo per subscription for creating large number of logic apps?

Comment: You are right, this is what the documentation says, but it does not make sense to have 1000 workflows of one Logic App instance... I think clarification from the product team is required.