# Logic App - Workflows per region per subscription 1000 - is limit to number of Logic app with per region or Instance per logic App

Tags: azure, workflow, limit, azure-logic-apps, subscription

There is limit of 1000 LogicApps workflows per region per subscription. Is the limit on the number of workflows we can create or the limit is on the number of running instances of the workflow?

Comment: Looks to be rather badly specified.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335005/upper-limit-on-the-number-of-azure-logic-apps-that-can-be-created-in-a-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 is the number of `Azure logic apps` you can create instead of instances.

Because a single `Azure Logic App Workflow` will have many instances running at the same time, it is unreasonable if only 1000 instances can be run at most.